# Magento Top Sellers By Category

Tags: magento, filter

Is it possible to display top sellers by category?

I have working code (below) that collects top sellers, but I can't figure out how to filter it by category!

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addOrderedQty()
->setStoreId($storeId)
->addStoreFilter($storeId)
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'DESC');
if (Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->isEnabled()) {
    $collection->getSelect()
    ->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_' . $storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
} else {
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'));
}
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
$collection->setPage(1, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below category filter in product collection

```
$product_collection->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(25,35,10,45)));
```